# how to parse nested json using javascript

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I am using the below code for rest outbound  call and this is working as expected., but in the second rest call i am trying to parse the json body but i am unable to retrieve the values

```
 try { 
 var r = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2('test', 'post');

 var response = r.execute();
 var responseBody = response.getBody();
 var httpStatus = response.getStatusCode();
 gs.print(response.getBody());
 gs.print(response.getStatusCode());
 var JsonObject = JSON.parse(responseBody);
 var sid = JsonObject.sid; 
 gs.print(sid);

 var r1 = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2('gateways', 'POST' );
 r1.setRequestHeader("X-chkp-sid",sid );
 var response1 = r1.execute();
 var responseBody1 = response1.getBody();
 var httpStatus = response1.getStatusCode()
 gs.print(response1.getBody());
 var JsonObject1 = JSON.parse(responseBody1);
 var objects = JsonObject1.objects;

 var database = new GlideRecord('u_test');
 database.initialize();
 database.query();
 database.deleteMultiple();

for (var key in objects) { // Loop through all the elements in the objects array

    var array_element=objects[key];

    for (var innerKey in array_element)//For each element, see if it contains key named cluster-member-names
        {
        if(innerKey == "cluster-member-names"){
            var cluster_array = array_element[innerKey];

            for (var clusterKey in cluster_array)// Print each element in the Cluster array 
                {
                gs.print(cluster_array[clusterKey]);
                                test = cluster_array[clusterKey];
                                gs.print(test);
                                var database = new GlideRecord('u_test');
                                database.initialize();
                                database.u_device = test;
                                database.insert();

            }
        }
    }
}
}
catch(ex) {
 var message = ex.message;
}
```

Please see one sample json file

```
{
  "objects" : [ {
    "uid" : "16b96771-d13a-4c11-b457-9c0861aaf3c8",
    "name" : "clus-cn-1",
    "type" : "CpmiGatewayCluster",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "16280a32-183a-4050-b698-f59dbe488da6",
      "name" : "dom-cn-1",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : {
      "access-policy-installed" : true,
      "access-policy-name" : "Standard",
      "access-policy-installation-date" : {
        "posix" : 1533629226178,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:07+0800"
      },
      "threat-policy-installed" : false
    },
    "operating-system" : "Gaia",
    "hardware" : "Open server",
    "version" : "R80",
    "ipv4-address" : "53.126.102.12",
    "network-security-blades" : {
      "firewall" : true,
      "site-to-site-vpn" : true
    },
    "management-blades" : { },
    "cluster-member-names" : [ "dev-cn-c1", "dev-cn-c2" ],
    "vpn-encryption-domain" : "addresses_behind_gw",
    "sic-status" : "uninitialized",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/cluster",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533629193330,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:06+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533629186803,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:06+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  }, {
    "uid" : "385c0a22-275c-4a70-9489-2b6ccd191eb8",
    "name" : "clus-cn-2",
    "type" : "CpmiGatewayCluster",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "6c2f639f-db32-4255-88ef-fb9b0e820051",
      "name" : "dom-cn-2",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : {
      "access-policy-installed" : true,
      "access-policy-name" : "Standard",
      "access-policy-installation-date" : {
        "posix" : 1533631724838,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:48+0800"
      },
      "threat-policy-installed" : false
    },
    "operating-system" : "Gaia",
    "hardware" : "Open server",
    "version" : "R80",
    "ipv4-address" : "53.126.102.16",
    "network-security-blades" : {
      "firewall" : true
    },
    "management-blades" : { },
    "cluster-member-names" : [ "dev-cn-c3", "dev-cn-c4" ],
    "vpn-encryption-domain" : "addresses_behind_gw",
    "sic-status" : "uninitialized",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/cluster",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533631690759,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:48+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533630083711,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:21+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  }, {
    "uid" : "4652da03-0e2f-4a0a-880c-338396be0818",
    "name" : "dev-cn-c1",
    "type" : "CpmiClusterMember",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "16280a32-183a-4050-b698-f59dbe488da6",
      "name" : "dom-cn-1",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : { },
    "ipv4-address" : "53.126.102.9",
    "interfaces" : [ {
      "interface-name" : "eth1",
      "ipv4-address" : "10.10.10.1",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.240",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 28,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : false,
        "ip-address-behind-this-interface" : "network defined by the interface ip and net mask",
        "leads-to-dmz" : false
      }
    }, {
      "interface-name" : "eth0",
      "ipv4-address" : "53.126.102.9",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.192",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 26,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : true
      }
    } ],
    "sic-status" : "communicating",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/Cluster_member",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533629193630,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:06+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533629187252,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:06+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  }, {
    "uid" : "2dbbbfd4-80ac-4fd9-b792-0a5b468c6409",
    "name" : "dev-cn-c2",
    "type" : "CpmiClusterMember",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "16280a32-183a-4050-b698-f59dbe488da6",
      "name" : "dom-cn-1",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : { },
    "ipv4-address" : "53.126.102.10",
    "interfaces" : [ {
      "interface-name" : "eth1",
      "ipv4-address" : "10.10.10.2",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.240",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 28,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : false,
        "ip-address-behind-this-interface" : "network defined by the interface ip and net mask",
        "leads-to-dmz" : false
      }
    }, {
      "interface-name" : "eth0",
      "ipv4-address" : "53.126.102.10",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.192",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 26,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : true
      }
    } ],
    "sic-status" : "communicating",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/Cluster_member",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533629193427,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:06+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533629188258,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:06+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  }, {
    "uid" : "6037e235-f19a-49ac-a39c-4889d979acbe",
    "name" : "dev-cn-c3",
    "type" : "CpmiClusterMember",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "6c2f639f-db32-4255-88ef-fb9b0e820051",
      "name" : "dom-cn-2",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : { },
    "ipv4-address" : "53.126.102.13",
    "interfaces" : [ {
      "interface-name" : "eth0",
      "ipv4-address" : "53.126.102.13",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.192",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 26,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : true
      }
    }, {
      "interface-name" : "eth1",
      "ipv4-address" : "10.10.20.1",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.240",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 28,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : false,
        "ip-address-behind-this-interface" : "network defined by the interface ip and net mask",
        "leads-to-dmz" : false
      }
    } ],
    "sic-status" : "communicating",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/Cluster_member",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533631689704,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:48+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533630084104,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:21+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  }, {
    "uid" : "022c44df-9271-46db-b782-da084c476dd2",
    "name" : "dev-cn-c4",
    "type" : "CpmiClusterMember",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "6c2f639f-db32-4255-88ef-fb9b0e820051",
      "name" : "dom-cn-2",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : { },
    "ipv4-address" : "53.126.102.14",
    "interfaces" : [ {
      "interface-name" : "eth0",
      "ipv4-address" : "53.126.102.14",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.192",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 26,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : true
      }
    }, {
      "interface-name" : "eth1",
      "ipv4-address" : "10.10.20.2",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.240",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 28,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : false,
        "ip-address-behind-this-interface" : "network defined by the interface ip and net mask",
        "leads-to-dmz" : false
      }
    } ],
    "sic-status" : "communicating",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/Cluster_member",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533631690171,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:48+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533630085006,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:21+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  }, {
    "uid" : "4f417c60-3541-4c0f-a542-9a100d857077",
    "name" : "dom_cn_1_Server",
    "type" : "CpmiHostCkp",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "16280a32-183a-4050-b698-f59dbe488da6",
      "name" : "dom-cn-1",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : { },
    "operating-system" : "Unknown OS",
    "hardware" : "Open server",
    "version" : "R80.10",
    "ipv4-address" : "53.126.102.11",
    "network-security-blades" : { },
    "management-blades" : {
      "network-policy-management" : true,
      "logging-and-status" : true
    },
    "sic-status" : "uninitialized",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/CheckPoint/Hosts/xHost_CP",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "Domain Management Server",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533621654552,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T14:00+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533621625970,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T14:00+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  }, {
    "uid" : "cebecd33-1efb-4530-9de9-7c666e588ee7",
    "name" : "dom_cn_2_Server",
    "type" : "CpmiHostCkp",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "6c2f639f-db32-4255-88ef-fb9b0e820051",
      "name" : "dom-cn-2",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : { },
    "operating-system" : "Unknown OS",
    "hardware" : "Open server",
    "version" : "R80.10",
    "ipv4-address" : "53.126.102.15",
    "network-security-blades" : { },
    "management-blades" : {
      "network-policy-management" : true,
      "logging-and-status" : true
    },
    "sic-status" : "uninitialized",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/CheckPoint/Hosts/xHost_CP",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "Domain Management Server",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533627992781,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T15:46+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533627964438,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T15:46+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  } ],
  "from" : 1,
  "to" : 8,
  "total" : 8
}
```

Using this code i am able to retrieve only "cluster-member-names" but i need to extract " domain name" and cluster name also
expecting response like below hence i can insert them in to corresponding table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMW8B.jpg)

Comment: The json is has extra keys at the bottom: from, to and total. Please correct the JSON.

Comment: i just checked again these keys are there in original file

Comment: If these keys are there in the original file, then you have added the complete json here. I'm assuming you want help with the "objects" property on the entire JSON, those 3 keys are outside on the json and thus it is not a valid json. Or you can simply add **{** at the beginning.

Comment: i just modified the json, this is response body of second rest call, you can see this in the second part of the code

Comment: "domain" is an object, so you just need to check if you're on the "domain" property (using an if statement like you do for the cluster-members) and then within that, print the inner "name" property of that property. I think it will be simply `array_element[innerKey].name`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but you can see domain name and cluster-member-names are under cluster name hence i need extract all these object at the same time like  "clustername |domainname|cluster-member-names"

Comment: I don't see any "clustername" property. I see an object like `"domain" : {
      "uid" : "16280a32-183a-4050-b698-f59dbe488da6",
      "name" : "dom-cn-1",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },` which is within an object within the "objects" array. "name" is a sub-property of the "domain" property. "cluster-member-names" is also at the same level as the "domain" object. The only difference is that "cluster-member-names" contains an array of strings whereas "domain" is an object with named properties.

Comment: If by "cluster name" you mean the "name" property which is on the same level as "domain" and "cluster-member-names" in each object in the objects array, then simply `array_element.name` will get you that.

Comment: please see cluster details    `"name" : "clus-cn-1",    "type" :CpmiGatewayCluster"`

Comment: Yes so like I said, `array_element.name` should return "clus-cn-1" from the first object.

Comment: if i use array_element.name  this will pull all the name  *** Script: clus-cn-1
*** Script: clus-cn-2
*** Script: dev-cn-c1
*** Script: dev-cn-c2
*** Script: dev-cn-c3
*** Script: dev-cn-c4
*** Script: dom_cn_1_Server
*** Script: dom_cn_2_Server

Comment: yes that's because you're looping through all the entries in the objects array. You didn't actually say precisely what output you wanted, so if you only want the first one, you'll have to stop after the first loop, or just access objects[0] explicitly.

Comment: another issue with this approach this will extract the cluster,domain and members individuality, because i am searching for specific innerkey "(innerKey == "cluster-member-names")", but i am looking for a way to get all these together like  cluser > domain > members ( members are part of domain and domain is part of cluster)

Comment: sorry, i just updated the expected output as image in to the main thread

Comment: "i am looking for a way to get all these together"...just add more if statements (as I already suggested!) to look for the other keys. Collect all the values you wanted into some object, and then at the end of all the if statements you can process the data (like inserting into your database, as your code seems to do now)

Comment: And, per your expected output image, it seems you want only the first two entries. So simply keep a count of the number of times you looped, and stop after the second time.

Answer (score 0):

Based in the question I think below should be a good starting point to explore further.

```
obj.objects.forEach(items => {
  let name = items.name;
  let domainName = items.domain.name;
  let memberNames = items['cluster-member-names'];
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyozLd60/9/)